# NSFetchedResultsController not reloading data automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode5, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have been stuck on a bug for hours now, I hope someone can help me.

I have a view controller that loads data using an NSFetchedResultsController (I am using core data),   that fetches all my objects that have a 'date' in the past, i.e. date < now. I want this data to be reloaded in front of the users eyes so I am using NSNotificationCenter to trigger the reload of the table when a task moves to 'out of date'. I also send a local notification when an objects date fires, then it moves into the 'complete' view controller I just explained.

Heres the weird part...
When the app comes from the background, and I switch to the 'complete objects' tab and they DO NOT SHOW UP. However, if I immediately close the app and re launch it, it all looks perfect. This exact same thing happens if I am on the 'complete objects' tab when the reload is supposed to happen, but if I am on another tab when the reload happens and switch over to it, it all looks perfect.

As far as I can tell my NSFetchedResultsController is NOT tracking changes that are made to the managed object context properly. I'm sure its a simple mistake I made but I can't seem to find it! Please help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup table view
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController section

- (NSFetchRequest *)myFetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"DBTask"];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]];

    NSPredicate *datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"taskDate < %@", [NSDate date]];
    NSPredicate *completePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"state == %d", DBTaskStateComplete];
    NSPredicate *latePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"state == %d", DBTaskStateLate];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:datePredicate, completePredicate, latePredicate, nil]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"taskDate" ascending:YES]];
    return fetchRequest;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    DBCoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [DBCoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self myFetchRequest];
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName"  cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see code to help find your mistake. Typically with fetched results controllers, btw, you don't reload based on notification unless you are using it to update the fetch parameters.

Comment: First. there is no need to listen to notifications in order to reload the data when using fetchresultscontrollers. These controllers will listen to the notification received by its parent managed object context and will update when needed. Second, post your delegate and fetch results controller initialization code .

Comment: Oh okay good to know then....I will post my code for it. Note that I am using a UIViewController with the table view added as a subview.

Comment: No matter what I do, the NSFetchedResultsController WILL NOT respond to changes in the managed object context. What I want to implement I have seen in dozens of other apps, what am I missing?

Comment: Just checking: when you insert a new object into the context, does the table view update? And if not, could you check if the object exists in the context? And when you analyse the fetched results controller's fetch request, is the object in it? And does your class declare that it is conforming to the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol?

Comment: I managed to make it work by cheating and calling... self.fetchedResultsController = nil; [self.fetchedResultsControler performFetch]; in viewWillAppear:. It may not be the best way but its the only way I could get the result I wanted since everything appears to be working correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the date `[NSDate date]` in your date predicate is generated at the time your predicate is initialized

That predicate isn't actively tracking the taskDate agains the current date, but against the date when the predicate was created.

Using the fetched results controller delegates here might not be the best way to achieve this, you could use a timer, reset the predicate and perform a new fetch every time the timer fires.